# Vanilla JS: open desired page based on concatenated values from two selects

Tags: javascript

**NOTE**: Plain/Vanilla JavaScript

I have two select boxes with different ids and a button. what I am trying to achieve is as follows:-

1. button cannot be clicked if one or both of the select box is empty - shows alert.
2. button cannot be clicked if the values of the first select box and second 
   select box is same - shows alert.
3. Know what values are selected in both the select boxes and store it as a variable and later add it to the dynamic link to goto the specific page when two of the variables are selected. (eg, if age1 and gender1 is selected, myvariable= age1gender1; if age2 and gender2 is selected, myvariable= age2gender2)
4. on button click, add the variable at the end of the link (eg, if age1 and gender1 is selected, goto https://www.mywebsite/age1gender1 and if age2 and gender2 is selected goto https://www.mywebsite/age2gender2).
5. goto page according to the users choice of select box.

```js
function first_select(sel) {
  var select1 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
function second_select(sel) {
  var select2 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
function myFunction() {
  if (selec1 == null || select2 == null) {
    alert("Both variables needs to be selected");
  } else if (select1 == null && select2 == null) {
    alert("Both variables needs to be selected");
  } else if (select1 == select2) {
    alert("Both variables cannot be same, please select different variables");
  } else if (select1 == age1 && select2 == gender1) {
    var age1gender1 = "age1gender1";
  } else if (select1 == age1 && select2 == age2) {
    var age1age2 = "age1age2";
  }
  window.open("https://www.mywebsite.com/'+age1gender1'")
}
```

```html
Select Row :
<select id="fselect" onchange="first_select(this);">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">-- select an option --</option>
  <option value="Age1">Age1 : Age of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender1">Gender1 : Gender of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Age2">Age2 : Age of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender2">Gender2 : Gender of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Age3">Age3 : Age of Third respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender3">Gender3 : Gender of Third respondent</option>
</select><br/>

Select Column :
<select id="sselect" onchange="second_select(this);">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">-- select an option --</option>
  <option value="Age1">Age1 : Age of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender1">Gender1 : Gender of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Age2">Age2 : Age of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender2">Gender2 : Gender of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Age3">Age3 : Age of Third respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender3">Gender3 : Gender of Third respondent</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Please fix your typos first. The snippet does not run now. Then the select1 and select2 are only available inside the functions they are set

Comment: You don't need `onchange` handlers for select boxes. You can read value from each select box in `myFunction` first, construct your variable value and then do condition checking

Comment: Lastly how to select more than one respondent? You do not have multiple in the select. I think you want to have a div you can repeat dependent on chosen number of respondents. I can now choose Age1 and Gender3

Comment: Also selecting none will return empty string and not null

Comment: Also, do you mean to have gender and age as separate fields? As of now, both are in same dropdown and using multiselect is prone to human errors. You're better off breaking down one select into two select elements. One to select gender and one to select age. Thus you have total 4 dropdowns - 2 for first respondent and 2 for second

Comment: @AdityaParab My guess is that the actual selects will contain something else

Comment: @rume fenud can you check the solution works in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build on this version. Yours has typos and logic issues (as in both have to be selected, but null is not a valid test)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var select1 = document.getElementById("fselect").value;
  var select2 = document.getElementById("sselect").value;
  if (!select1 || !select2) {
    alert("Both variables needs to be selected");
    return;
  } else if (select1 == select2) {
    alert("Both variables cannot be same, please select different variables");
    return;    
  }
  
  var parms=[select1,select2].sort().join("");
  console.log(parms)
  window.open("https://www.mywebsite.com/"+parms);
}
```

```html
Select Row :
<select id="fselect">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">-- select an option --</option>
  <option value="Age1">Age1 : Age of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender1">Gender1 : Gender of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Age2">Age2 : Age of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender2">Gender2 : Gender of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Age3">Age3 : Age of Third respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender3">Gender3 : Gender of Third respondent</option>
</select><br/>

Select Column :
<select id="sselect">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">-- select an option --</option>
  <option value="Age1">Age1 : Age of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender1">Gender1 : Gender of first respondent</option>
  <option value="Age2">Age2 : Age of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender2">Gender2 : Gender of Second respondent</option>
  <option value="Age3">Age3 : Age of Third respondent</option>
  <option value="Gender3">Gender3 : Gender of Third respondent</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: how can i acheive like this :-  if age1 as first row is selected and gender1 is selected as second row, then goto abc.com/age1gender1  but also if gender1 is selected as first row and age1 is selected as second row, goto abc.com/age1gender1 and so on for  other variables.

Comment: i have a table with lots of columns. Age1, age2, age3, gender1, gender2 and gender3 are few columns of the table. I want users to select the column names and goto desired page (a single page that displays only two columns from the entire table. for eg, if the page is "abc.com/age1gender2" it contains table with two columns age1 and gender1) to view the table. so if user selects age1 from first column or second column, it doesnt matter.

Comment: No. select age3 and age1 from both the columns and you will know why.

Answer (score -2):

i hope this will work :)

```js
(function (){
  document.getElementById("onSubmit").addEventListener("click", function(){
   // fetching the values of two select box
   var firstSelectBox = document.getElementById("firstSelectBox");
   var firstText = firstSelectBox.options[firstSelectBox.selectedIndex].text;
   var secondSelectBox = document.getElementById("secondSelectBox");
   var secondText = secondSelectBox.options[secondSelectBox.selectedIndex].text;
   // checking the conditions empty or same
   if((firstText && secondText) && (firstText !== secondText)){
     window.open("https://www.example.com/"+ firstText + secondText)
   console.log("https://www.example.com/"+ firstText + secondText)
   }else{
     alert("either the values of two select box is same or any of the select box value is empty")
   }
  })


})();
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>First Select Box</h2>
  <select id="firstSelectBox">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
    <h2>Second Select Box</h2>
    <select id="secondSelectBox">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  
  <p><button id="onSubmit">Submit</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: updated the answer with pure vanilla js ! can you check right now @mplungjan

Comment: Now it is not much different than mine

Comment: thank you :) don't know one more down vote is there :) even though solution works

Comment: It could be the person no longer monitors the answers. Anyway, your code is  unnecessarily complex with 3 lines to get the text of each of the selects instead of the value

Comment: Also you are not telling the user what is wrong. You just fail silently

Comment: It is not up to me to decide if this answer is answering the question.

Comment: @mplungjan i hope this a community were we will  get a better understanding on the concepts by helping each others, so thats y when u suggested i updated the solution in a better way.

Comment: Sure. That is why I kept commenting ;)

Comment: how can i acheive like this :- if age1 as first row is selected and gender1 is selected as second row, then goto abc.com/age1gender1 but also if gender1 is selected as first row and age1 is selected as second row, goto abc.com/age1gender1 and so on for other variables.